# Can I sync my Kindle books with my Android phone?

Tags: htc-desire, email, ebook-reader, amazon-kindle, ebooks

I have just bought a Kindle and the cool thing about it is you have an email address `@kindle.com` where you can send your books and it automatically converts it to a .azw and syncs it with your Kindle. I was under the impression it would also sync the books with *all* your devices, including the Kindle app on my Android phone (Isn't this the *whispersync* thing?). However, it doesn't seem to do this. Is there way to also sync all my books to my phone as well as my Kindle automatically?

Comment: Have you tried manually syncing?

Comment: @Matthew: With a large number of books, this is effort.

Comment: I meant through the app itself (Menu -> Sync) but I guess that won't help according to Matt's answer.

Comment: That might work according to the other Matt's comment. I never tried adding a .mobi file directly to the sd card, I only tried a pdf and txt.

Answer (score 4):

It currently doesn't sync outside content with your phone, no pdfs, txts, emails... only kindle books you get from amazon.  I have tried to manually load pdfs with no luck. I believe the functionality is planned but not yet implemented.

Comment: I've managed to get downloaded (free) .mobi files into Kindle by simply copying them to the 'kindle' folder on my sd card. I haven't tried PDFs. I got my .mobi files from the Project Gutenberg website.

Comment: @Matt H didn't know that you could do that! Sounds like I need to start copying some of my outside content across from my Kindle to my phone.

Comment: @Matt H: It worked on my WildFire running Froyo (Android 2.2) but only after I force closed the Kindle app and started it up again. It didn't happen immediately. Just so people trying that know. Thanks and +1 for confirming what I suspected though.

Answer (score 2):

There is a folder on your sd card called Kindle.
Just move the book there.
If you are having trouble downloading it, try dropbox.
Worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your Manage Your Kindle page on Amazon (the same page where you set the email address up) you can see that the Kindle email address is specifically assigned to one Kindle device. If you had more than one Kindle device, then you can assign different email addresses to each. The upside of this for Kindle owners is that you and other family members can both have Kindle's on the same account (and thus share books) but you can avoid bombarding anyone else with your documents (if you did want to send to both at the same time, you just list both addresses in the "To" box when you send the email).

The fact that Amazon don't allow you to set up an email address for any non-Kindle device (and I have the Kindle app installed on my laptop as well as my phone) suggests to me that they're keeping the conversion service as a "value-add" incentive for people who've bought a Kindle device. It's also worth bearing in mind that the conversion process will use some of their computing resources and cost them (albeit a tiny amount compared to the rest of their business) this could be the reason that it's only open to paying customers.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/download_windows) from calibre-ebook.com tho convert your `.mobi` files to `.epub` files (it does `.epub` to `.mobi` as well) either singly or en mass, so you can read your books on all devices. Hope this helps.